# Values for Resistances in LTSpice

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, ltspice

I need to implement the following circuit in LTSpice but I don't know if my schematic is ok and what values \$C{inf}\$ and \$R_2\$ should be.

The following constraints are imposed:

- \$V_{CC}=10V\$
- \$V_{CM} = 1.5V\$
- \$R_1= 15k\Omega\$
- \$Vg\$ is  a  sine  wave  with  a  frequency  of  1  kHz, whose amplitude  will  be  chosen  so  as  to ensure minimal distortion of the output signal (i.e. \$v_0\$ should also be a sine wave);

I need to choose a value for \$R_2\$ and \$C_{inf}\$ in order to have a (theoretical)gain value \$A_v=1500\$. Also, how can I compute the theoretical   expressions of the DC collector currents of bipolar transistors  \$Q_1–Q_8\$, considering \$V_{BE}\approx 0.6V\$ and the theoretical expression of the small-signal voltage gain \$A_v= \dfrac{v_o}{v_g}\$?

The first picture is the schematic and the second one the LTSpice implementation.

[image: schematic_1]
[image: lt_spice_schematic]

Comment: This is what **real** circuit designer do: **before** you enter this circuit into LTSpice you should do some **hand calculations** to determine the values of all components and choose the biasing currents that you want. Only after you know those and the main parameters like gain and bandwidth should you draw the schematic in LTSpice. Then you use LTSPice to do a DC operating point simulation to confirm that all biasing currents are what you want them to be. Then you do an AC analysis and confirm the bandwith.

Comment: The "draw circuit, see what I get" approach doesn't work when you're new to this and it **will** confuse you and not help **at all** in understanding circuit design. Trust me, most of us have been there. Get your approach correct now and then benefit from that for as long as you're going to design circuits. Just a tip from 25 years circuit design experience ;-)

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie my biggest problem is that I received this assignment without an theoretical support, and idk where to start from...That's why I'm asking here in order to solve something...

Comment: You haven't "earthed" your 10 volt supply.

Comment: @Andyaka why should I do thiis and how to do this?

Comment: What Andyaka says is that a ground is missing on the neg (-) terminal of the upper right 10-V \$V_{cc}\$ supply.

Comment: @VerbalKint yeah, but on my scheme it's nothing there..So I should only swap the terminals, put - instead of plus?

Comment: I don't understand your comment : the 10-V source is biasing your circuit so its neg. terminal should be connected to the other grounds like the ground of \$R_1\$, emitters of \$Q_8\$ and \$Q_6\$. If not, the source is floating and does nothing. By the way, your ground symbol is the little triangle pointing downward.

Comment: @VerbalKint I'm implementing the first scheme, it's not connected to grounds or something..I know, it's weird but idk what to do..

Comment: *I received this assignment without an theoretical support,* For sure you have a book or course materials for this. If the finished circuit was given to you, with all currents, voltages and component values given, are you able to analyze the circuit and determine its gain **without using a simulator**? If not, study: small signal circuit analysis.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I've computed Av as being 0.972, is this correct? Also, about the theoretical expressions of the DC collector currents of bipolar transistors Q1–Q8, idk how to do this..

Comment: You're thinking too much in expressions, what do the transistors **do**? For example: Q6, Q7, Q8: bias current mirror. Determine the current through Q6, that's the output current of the mirror. Then we know the biasing current of the diffpair Q1, Q2. Then what is the gm of this diffpair?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Q3, Q4 and respectively Q6, Q7, Q8 are current mirrors – the
transistors in a current mirror have the same base-emitter voltage and therefore
the collector currents are equal.

Comment: Is there anything in http://aries.ucsd.edu/NAJMABADI/CLASS/ECE102/12-F/NOTES/ECE102_F12-LecSet-7A.pdf  that is familiar to you? That's small signal analysis.

Comment: My recent answer added to previous query http://tinyurl.com/y7yohcgj

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I'll study it, thanks.